# Can anyone help me with a excel formula converted to a SQL syntax?

Tags: sql, excel-formula

```
=IF(OR(AND(K1471="",I1471<>"Completed",DAYS(DATEVALUE("06-14-2021"),F1471)>14),AND(OR(Q1471<>"To Be Worked",Q1471<>""),I1471="Completed",DAYS(DATEVALUE("06-14-2021"),F1471)>14),AND(S1471>=K1471,S1471<>"",Q1471<>"To Be Worked")),"Keep",IF(AND(I1471<>"Completed",DAYS(DATEVALUE("06-14-2021"),F1471)>14),"Keep","Remove"))
```

This is what I got so far.

```
, CASE WHEN (
([NuanceFileDate]=''OR [NuanceStatus]<>'Completed')
 AND (DATEDIFF(d,'06-14-2021',[DateOfService])> 14)
)
AND 

([McReviewStatus] <>'To Be Worked' OR [McReviewStatus] <> '')
AND ([NuanceStatus]='Completed' AND (DATEDIFF(d,'06-14-2021',[DateOfService])> 14)
AND ([LastUpdateDate]>= [NuanceFileDate] AND [LastUpdateDate]<> '' AND [McReviewStatus] <>'To Be Worked')
)
THEN 'Keep'
ELSE
(
CASE WHEN ([NuanceStatus]<>'Completed') AND DATEDIFF(d,'06-14-2021',[DateOfService])> 14
THEN 'Keep'
ELSE 'Remove'
END
)
END
  AS [COLUMN T]
```

Comment: Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please remember how to [edit] your questions for example to include your own attempt and a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: It would depend on the specific database. What database you want to convert to?

Comment: SQL SERVER is the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many END's and too much nesting.

It should look like this (as you said in SQL Server):

```
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN ([NuanceFileDate]= '' OR [NuanceStatus]<>'Completed')
                AND DATEDIFF(d,'06-14-2021',[DateOfService])> 14
                AND ([McReviewStatus] <>'To Be Worked' OR [McReviewStatus] <> '')
                AND ([NuanceStatus]='Completed' AND DATEDIFF(d,'06-14-2021',[DateOfService])> 14)
                AND ([LastUpdateDate]>= [NuanceFileDate] AND [LastUpdateDate]<> '' AND [McReviewStatus] <>'To Be Worked')
            THEN 'Keep'
        WHEN [NuanceStatus]<>'Completed'
            AND DATEDIFF(d,'06-14-2021',[DateOfService])> 14
            THEN 'Keep'
        ELSE 'Remove'
    END AS [COLUMN T]
FROM YourTable
```

The above should work for you.. it works on my machine in SQL Server Management Studio.